# vc++ MFC detecting which CButton was clicked

Tags: c++, button, visual-c++, mfc, click

Sorry for this question of a debutant, I am new in MFC world, I have some files, and each file has some optional instructions to perform,  for that, when I open the file, I have to create for each Instruction, Button when clicked call a specific external script or action, my problem now is how can I assign the click event, is there a way to catch or identify the source of the click.

Comment: See the docs [`BN_CLICKED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bn-clicked)  _"...Sent when the user clicks a button....The LOWORD contains the button's control identifier. The HIWORD specifies the notification code...."_

Comment: @Richard Critten, I spent all my day trying to found solution, thank you very much.